# Enabling EditText corrupts RecyclerView items

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-edittext, android-recyclerview

I have a problem with flickering **RecyclerView** items when my **EditText** is enabled.

When I disable the EditText, everything is fine:

[image: pic. 1 (disabled)]

But when I enable it in the XML (`android:enabled="true"`) or with code (`setEnabled(true)`) the RecyclerView items go white or pink, depending on the EditText focus:

[image: pic. 2 (enabled)]

This happens only on some devices and never on the emulator.

In the Google Play Developer Console report, only the screenshots taken on Nexus 5 had this problem.

I also have Nexus 5 device (the older one) and it's there as well.

<strike>I'm not posting any code right now as I think it doesn't matter since it happens just by enabling the EditText.</strike>

Have you seen something like this? Do you know what causes such effect?

**Edit 1:**

As you can see, also the Spinners get corrupted.

**Edit 2:**

I have uploaded the whole repository to a temporary public project: [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/NerV-0-sol/temp-project/tree/alpha-4)

(Look for `RatesFragment.java` and `res/layout/fragment_rates.xml`)

The code is a mess right now. I was experimenting with a few approaches and ended up with this issue in the middle of the night.

Comment: How should anybody help you without seeing what you are doing in code?

Comment: Very interesting. Is this problem OS dependent as well?

Comment: Can u show the xml lalout for this?

Comment: or try repait it with add color to edittext via java. But htis is interested problem

Comment: @Robert Please see my edit with a GitLab link